# How can I upload files to Amazon S3 using react-dropzone?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-dropzone

I've been working on a project involving the [react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) package. I successfully built a container me to add files but now I can't figure out how I can upload these files to my Amazon S3 bucket. When I add files, it creates these "file" objects but all it contains is information like the name, size, path, etc. Doesn't seem like it contains the actual file itself. Even the file path isn't the full file path, its just the name of the file. The documentation doesn't have any information on what you can do after dragging a file to the browser. I don't believe this entire package that has 1.3 million NPM downloads per week is all for display purposes. I'm still new to the world of web-dev so there's probably something obvious I don't understand. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the FormData object
Here's an example using axios

```
for (let i = 0; i < newFiles.length; i++) {
    let file = newFiles[i]
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("file", file)
    formData.append("otherProperties", otherProperties)
    await axios.post(url, formData, {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        successfulUploads.push(res.data)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

react-dropzone is a simple component used to get File objects from the user. These Files implement the File API found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

The File object itself is the *file*. It also has properties such as size, path, etc.

react-dropzone does not handle any sort of uploading, or do anything with those files, thats your responsibility.

As far as I know, you cannot directly upload a file to S3 from the web. You will need a server/lambda endpoint to generate a signed url, that you can then use in your client to PUT the file to.

So it becomes a 3 step process.

1. Get the File from react-dropzone
2. Request a signedUrl from your endpoint
3. PUT the file to the signedUrl

Here is an example: https://medium.com/@kevinwu/client-side-file-upload-to-s3-using-axios-c9363ec7b530

Comment: how can we upload multiple images at once?

Comment: @chandara you would need multiple signed s3 upload urls. One for each file.

Comment: "react-dropzone does not handle any sort of uploading" That's not true. It literally has props for uploading files.

Comment: @AlxVallejo if you read the docs for `react-dropzone` it states very clearly: `This lib is not a file uploader; as such, it does not process files or provide any way to make HTTP requests to some server`

Comment: @Benjamin Right but there's a whole section for autoUpload functionality and s3 integrations: https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/s3 I think it's pretty outdated tho